# Where I went wrong in this chain of arguments - Linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, hamel-basis

Let $AB = I_n$. $A$ and $B$ are nonsingular, square matrices of size $n$.

Let $A_{r1}$ be the first row of $A$. The products $A_{r1} B_j = 0, j \in \{2,\dots,N\}$. $B_j$ is the $j^{th}$ column of $B$.

Does this means that $A_{r1}$ is not in the span of $B_j, j \in \{2,\dots,N\}$ ? Yes.

Let $C$ be matrix whose rows are $B_j^T$,$ j \in \{2,\dots,N\}$. $A_{r1}$ is in the nullspace of $C$.

Since nullspace and rowspace of $C$ are orthogonal, $\{A_{r1}^T,B_j,j \in \{2,\dots,N\}\}$ form a linearly independent set, hence a basis for $R^n$.

$\{B_j\}$ $,j \in \{1,\dots,N\}$ forms a basis for $R^n$.

Is $A_{r1}^T$ a scalar multiple of $B_1$? Need not be.

Does  $\{A_{r1}^T,B_j\}$,$j \in \{1,\dots,N\}$ form a basis or linearly independent set. No.

Because no basis set of $R^n$ can contain more than $n$ members of $R^n$.

What is wrong with this chain of arguments?

Comment: why do you think there's something wrong with it?

Comment: @Exodd {ATr1,Bj},j∈{1,…,N} contains n+1 elements from R^n.

Comment: $B_1$ does not have to be orthogonal to the other columns.

Comment: @KBS. Agreed. But $B_1$ is linearly independent of other columns of $B$ as well as first row of $A$.

Comment: $A_{r1}^T$ is linearly independent of $B_j, j = \{2,...,n\}$. But $A_{r1}^T$ is linearly dependent to $B_j, j = \{1...,n\}$. The inclusion of $B_1$ introduces linear dependence.

Comment: I still don't see what's wrong. All arguments seem ok

Comment: We have that $A_{r1}^T$ is linearly dependent on $B_1,\ldots,B_n$.